# Espresso Swipe on List Item of RecyclerView present inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-espresso

A ViewPager contains a RecyclerView. I am attempting to swipe an item in that RecyclerView, but unfortunately at times,the ViewPager gets swiped. Is this a bug in Espresso? The following code has been used to achieve this.

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview)).perform(
                RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(1, swipeLeft()));
```

Looking out for a clear distinction between swiping the list item and the ViewPager

Comment: Hey, Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to prevent viewpager intercept touch event in recyclerview, like this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent e) {
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                recyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not related to Espresso,rather to general motion event handling.

Comment: Agree with @NikolaDespotoski on this